# How to echo block title render in specific <div> D7

Tags: blocks

After creating a dynamic block I need to print block title in specific div or customize it to add css class .
Please check image for more details

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add classes to block you can use below module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class

To add class to block title there is similar question before:

[Adding classes to block title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63790/adding-classes-to-block-title)

Thanks!

Comment: thanks bro, solved by

@block.tpl.php

<section id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
      <div class="section-title">
          <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?> >
            <a href="#">
              <?php print $title ?></a>
          </h2>
      </div>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php print $content ?>

</section>

because after adding css from block configuration interface mini tags distorted in this case thanks U

Comment: @MohamedHafez  not a problem :)